# Average time difference for each day Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of user activity, with user ID's and time of activity.
I'm trying to calculate the average time difference between activities for each user. I've managed to do this when a user is active for only 1 day, but I struggle with instances when the user is active for multiple days.

for example:

| User ID | Activity Date | week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7/26/2021 8:29:01 PM | 1 |
| 1 | 7/26/2021 8:28:01 PM | 1 |
| 1 | 7/26/2021 8:32:01 PM | 2 |

I used this code, and it works fine:

```
d=d.sort_values('Activity Date').groupby(['User ID','week'])['Activity Date'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().mean()).dt.total_seconds()/60
```

My issue is when the user is active on multiple days, with my code I still get an average but it doesn't represent the activity the way I need it.

| User ID | Activity Date | week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7/25/2021 8:29:01 PM | 1 |
| 1 | 7/26/2021 8:29:01 PM | 1 |
| 1 | 7/26/2021 8:32:01 PM | 1 |
| 1 | 7/25/2021 8:28:01 PM | 1 |
| 1 | 7/30/2021 8:32:01 PM | 2 |
| 1 | 7/30/2021 8:30:01 PM | 2 |

I would like to first compute the average for each day, and than compute the average of averages.

My code gives the result of:  week 1: 481.333 minutes,  week 2: 2 minutes

I want it to be: for week 1: **2 minutes** (for 25/07- 1 minute difference, for 26/07- 3 minute difference=> so the mean is 2 minutes).

I would really appreciate your help or any suggestions!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a double `groupby`, first on user and day, then on user:

```
df['Activity Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Activity Date'])

day = df['Activity Date'].dt.normalize()

out = (df
   .sort_values(by=['User ID', 'Activity Date'])
   .groupby(['User ID', day])
   .diff()
   .groupby(df['User ID']).mean()
)
```

Output:

```
          Activity Date
User ID                
1       0 days 00:02:00
```

##### also grouping by week

```
out = (df
   .sort_values(by=['User ID', 'Activity Date'])
   .groupby(['User ID', day])
   .diff()
   .groupby([df['User ID'], df['week']]).mean()
)
```

Comment: What is the difference and please provide the full/explicit expected output in your question

Comment: I need another step of group by - by week number. So a row for each user for each week

Comment: So add `df['week']` in the last `groupby` ;)

Comment: thank again! did you mean like this:  out = (df
   .sort_values(by=['User ID', 'Activity Date'])
   .groupby(['User ID', day])
   .diff()
   .groupby(df['User ID','week']).mean()
)   unfortunately I get an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: thank you again, but I unfortunately still get an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Have you run: `df['Activity Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Activity Date'])`?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example that triggers the error?

Comment: maybe its because the 'week' column is of type object? when I try to do it without the 'week' column it does work.

Comment: @kri I don't think so, the code works well for me… please provide the output of `df.to_dict('list')`

Comment: it's just a list of number of weeks, like this for example: '3','1','2'